# Passing properties from parent to child with & operator

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to pass down css properties from a parent to child.

For example:

With LESS file:

```
.button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    &-blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    &-red {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Which outputs to:

```
.button-blue {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: blue;
}

.button-red {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Meloman you are testing the flag as duplicate feature? how the question is a duplicate? it has nothing to do with CSS at all

Comment: Sorry, I was flagging another question. wrong manipulation with my browser !